# Bootstrap col-md-3 class is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please find the following code snippet. Where `col-md-3` class is not working. I have different styles for small, medium and large screens which is done by using media queries. But the trouble is arising only for `col-md-3`. Any ideas would be helpful.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xl-2 col xyz">
      <p class="spaceno textabovein3">Book Your Package</p>
      <div class="img1 imga ">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="textonimg">Select a date and a game and tell us your group numbers</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xl-2 col xyz">
      <p class="spaceno textabovein3">We will do the Rest</p>
      <div class="img2 imga ">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="textonimg">We will organise premium seats, Aussie Rules 101 and direction booklet and home team merchandise</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xl-2 col xyz">
      <p class="spaceno textabovein3">Receive the Box</p>
      <div class="img3 imga ">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="textonimg">Your package will be delivered to your hotel or home or you can pick it up at the stadium.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xl-2 col xyz">
      <p class="spaceno textabovein3">Get to the Game!</p>
      <div class="img4 imga ">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="textonimg">Read your new AFL rules guide and local tips booklet, put on your scarf and proceed to enjoy the game!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you mean *"Col-md-3 not working"* ?

Comment: I want four images to come side by side in a row. I'm able to see this in small(i have vertically stacked the images for small screen) and large screen specification. But for medium screen it shows the images in a vertical column, instead of a row.

Comment: Works for me? You can clearly see both breakpoints when shrinking the screen. Maybe you want to adjust your breakpoints if it recognizes a screen size you want to be medium as small?

Comment: It shows vertically because if you're in medium devices, you have `col-md-3` * 4 is equal to 12columns, so it means the output should be vertical.

Comment: @SourceOverflow it is stacking on top of each other below 990px.

Comment: @Jonjie shouldn't that mean that the row will occupy the entire width of the page since that'll be 12 columns. But this problem persists even if I change the c0l-md-3 to col-md-2

Comment: @Nightshade Which is the expected result? You even wrote in your question that you did that on purpose

Comment: @SourceOverflow I wanted the elements to be stacked on top of each other below 640px and in a four column layout for screen size above that. In the answer I accepted, I found out that col-md is for screen sizes above 992px. I'm changing my main code now to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In media queries of bootstrap, medium devices' width is set to minimum 992px. To display your page to smaller device you could use col-sm-* classes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid